# How to create multiple headers in Wordpress?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, header

How to create multiple headers in Wordpress? My file includes footer.php, footer-login.php, functions.php, header.php, header-login.php, index.php and page.php.

In my header-login.php file,

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>??????</title>
    <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="max-age=8640000" />

    <?php wp_head();?>
  </head>
<body>
```

For my `index.php`,

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="main">
  <div id="content">
    <p><?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?></p>
    <p><?php the_content(__('(more...)')); ?></p>
    <p><?php endwhile; else: ?></p>
    <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
    <p><?php endif; ?></p>
  </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

`Page.php`

```
<?php 
  if(is_page(2)) {
    get_header('login');
  } else {
    get_header();
  }
  wp_head();
?>
```

Why can I still get the blank page when I open the website?

Result
[image: Result]

File/Folder
[image: File/Folder]

Comment: Check the error logs, a blank page suggested a error 500 server error due to a PHP problem most of the time.

Comment: where can check?

Comment: It depends where the website is. Are you using a web host or doing this locally? Look for an `errors.log` file.

Comment: do you get ???? as tab title ? you do not have any output in header.php. You are doing the call to header in right way. Something else seems to be out of order.